.NET MAUI does not find namespaces
My .NET MAUI application suddenly stopped working when I tried to compile and debug it on a emulator.
I am being told that the namespace MauiApplication in /platforms/android/MainApplication.cs can't be found, and I don't understand why, since I did not change anything before the error occured. Simmilar errors occur when I try to debug on Windows/other Android Emulators.
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace MAUI_Testing
{
    [Application]
    public class MainApplication : MauiApplication   //MainApplication is not found
    {
        public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownership)
            : base(handle, ownership)
        {
        }

        protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
    }
}

I have installed the following nugget packages:

CommunityToolkit.Maui Version="9.0.2"
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.7"
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.7"
Microsoft.Maui.Controls Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.7"
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.7" Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.7"
Microsoft.Maui.Essentials Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.7"
Microsoft.Maui.Graphics Version="9.0.0-preview.6.24327.7"

I know that some of these packages are unnecessary, but I tried fixing hte error by installing a bunch of packages that were mentione din articles related to MauiApplication and simmilar errors.
I am new to .NET MAUI and don't reall know if this is my fault or just something being outdated/misconfigured.
If you need more information, please ask for it.
EDIT: I tried creating a test project, and it has them same error. What should I do? Reinstall Visual Studio? Use another device? Reinstall Windows?

Have you renamed the project name? Does this problem also occur in the default MAUI project?

I found the problem myself: I updated my Nuget packages to V 9.x while using .NET 8.x. A downgrade resolved the problem. Never install the preview versions.

Just feel like I need to point out: It's called Nuget, not Nugget :)
